# Yii - include(PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii

I am getting that error with Yii and it points to /var/www/php_project/yii/yii_framework/framework/YiiBase.php(418)

I have these lines included in my php.ini file:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension_dir=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

I'm using sqlite.  And when I go to the requirements page for Yii:

It has warnings for:

```
PDO extension
PDO SQLite extension
```

I'm pretty new to php and completely new to Yii.  What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 extension_dir=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

extension_dir is for pointing where your extension dlls are so it should look like this

```
extension_dir="C:\wserver\lib\phpext" (Example only, path differs based on your install)
```